# Start does not exist in the namespace AppCenter

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

After installing the AppCenter SDK and trying to initialize it in Xamarin forms using this method:

```
AppCenter.Start("ios={Your App Secret};android={Your App Secret};uwp={Your App Secret}", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
```

I got this error:

```
The type or namespace 'Start' does not exist in the namespace 'AppCenter' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Xamarin Forms app, please make sure the packages are installed in all the projects that reference any libraries. The error that you see is mostly because the packages aren't added to all the projects.

Comment: It's very deceptive because you can still run the app loading the other AppCenter modules with no errors.  But sure enough, after troubleshooting something else, I found I had never actually installed the base package "Microsoft.AppCenter".  After installing the package and restarting VS, I can now resolve the method properly.

Answer (score 11):

Even though I was importing `using Microsoft.AppCenter;` for some reason it wasn't resolving.

I had to use:

```
Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.Start(...);
```

Comment: This is very true and sad!! On other hand, my team was using Microsoft.AppInsights.Xamarin, it got deprecated, then changed to HockeySDK which also got deprecated... now they have to change again and these little problems are not allowing them to work easily!! They planned a strategy to use an abstract **IWhateverSdk** interface, but the different ways that each library connects to a DI container makes the effort useless. Cannot believe that an AppInsights element is being deprecated that relatively fast!!